# Error in summary.formula : matrix variables must have column dimnames

Tags: r, statistics

I am new to R, and I can't fix the bug after searching for one hour. It seems that there's no similar problem posted before.

I followed the instruction from *https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/* ,and want to test the proportional assumption for my data.

Following is my code:

```
sf <- function(y) {
  c('Y>=1' = qlogis(mean(y >= 1)),
    'Y>=2' = qlogis(mean(y >= 2)),
    'Y>=3' = qlogis(mean(y >= 3)),
    'Y>=3' = qlogis(mean(y >= 4)),
    'Y>=3' = qlogis(mean(y >= 5)))
}

(s <- with(dat, summary(as.numeric(implied_rating) ~ GDP + importance, fun = sf)))
```

But the error occurs.

> "Error in summary.formula(matrix(as.numeric(implied_rating)) ~
>   matrix(GDP) +  :    matrix variables must have column dimnames"

What should I do?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: PS: dat is my dataset. The implied rating is my dependent variable, and GDP and importance are my independent variables.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I thought dimnames is colnames...
Just mannually set dimnames to every column.
But I still wonder if there's better way to solve the problem.